# Можно ли использользовать С++ в Unity3D вместо С#?

Tags: c#, c++, unity3d

Можно ли использользовать С++ в Unity3D вместо С# ?

Comment: Ответ скорее нет, чем да. Возможно но очень сложно и того не стоит и вообще не рекомендуется. По факту, переход на шарп для после с++ очень легкий, синтаксис почти такой же и почти все передается по ссылке.

Comment: Даже если и можно, то это реализовано сторонними инструментом, и всё равно будет транслироваться в C# - то есть смысла в этом никакого вообще. Официально Unity умеет только C#, JavaScript и Boo. Если вам хочется сиплюсплюсу, ваш выбор - Unreal Engine :)

Comment: а в юнити DllImport есть? Может написать логику возвращающую координаты игроков, врагов и всякую всячину на c++ подгрузить динамически c++ библиотеку и использовать c# на unity в качестве интерпретатора логики отрисовывая графику?

Comment: Ответ есть на братском английском комьюнити, двигался я верно в прошлом комменте:) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923595/how-to-use-a-c-dll-in-unity3d

Comment: @xSx DllImport есть, сам использовал в критичных по скорости местах. Но я бы не советовал, если хочется писать на С++ то есть кокос какой-нибудь.

Comment: Думаю нет (разве только импорт вспомогательных dll). Т.к. на Unity не полный C#. Там классы подрезаны специально (может, чтоб соблюсти кроссплатформенность в результате конвертации в нативный язык в процессе сборки). Например невозможно использовать Task...Поэтому производя написание кода на предоставленных инструментах, а не на с++ вы не вылезете за рамки недозволенного и потом не придется искать костыли, чтоб завести всё.......Если же вы беспокоитесь только о том, что с++ быстрее работает, то не стоит беспокоится. Весь код в Unity конвертируется с помощью `IL2CPP` как раз именно в него...

Comment: @eastwing вроде бы CryEngine на плюсах. А unreal на чем-то своем.

Comment: Ну то есть может быть и можно. Но зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Есть возможность подключать C++ные DLLки. dll файлы на с++, подключаешь к юнити и вызываешь уже на C#.

Но моё мнение: Unity позволяет писать скрипты на трех языках: C#, Java, Boo. Все прописано в документации.
Все остальное – издевательство над самим собой. :)

Comment: На Java? Вы уверенны, что не JavaScript?